# Changing Aptana3's auto bracket completion to { ... } instead of {...}

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I'm programming in Ruby, where convention often dictates spacing around curly brakets like so:

```
grades = { Rob: 82, Billy: 58 }
```

I have been trying to get Aptana to change it's auto braket completion feature to insert a space when I type '{' so that I end up with my cursor in the middle of two curly braces which already have space padding like so: { | }.

I have edited my ruby ruble smart_typing_pairs variable from

smart_typing_pairs['source.ruby'] = ['"', '"', '|', '|', '(', ')', **'{', '}'**, '[', ']', "'", "'", '`', '`']

to

smart_typing_pairs['source.ruby'] = ['"', '"', '|', '|', '(', ')', **'{', ' }'**, '[', ']', "'", "'", '`', '`']

(Notice the space in the second })

But this just breaks bracket completion for braces. I can't seem to find an automatic string replacement feature in Aptana either.

Can anyone give me any hints? Thanks!